# A single rewrite rule for multiple pages in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, url-rewriting

I have to created custom rewrite rule in my class.

I've made 1 rewrite rule but for multiple different pages.

```
add_rewrite_rule('^car/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?&product_cat_temp=$matches[1]&brand_or_product=$matches[2]', 'top');
```

URL example for brand:
`project.local/car/sport/BMW/` **BMW** is brand

URL example for product:
`project.local/mobil/sport/bmw-i8/`
**bmw-i8** is product name

so, when `query_var` brand_or_product is available, I will detect it first, is it belonging to product or brand

if the result is product, I will set the query_var `product` = bmw-i8 and set the query var `post_type` = `product`

if the result is brand, I will set the query_var `product_cat` = sport and set the query_var `brand` = BMW

After that, I will direct the link to each page: **product page** or **shop page**

Is this way possible?

Comment: The answer of TBI is right, you just need to remove the `&` after `?`

Answer (score 1):

It will work, just need little change. Use :

```
add_rewrite_rule('^car/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?product_cat_temp=$matches[1]&brand_or_product=$matches[2]', 'top');
```